# Control Flow for pieces

Tags: c++11, control-flow

So basically, I'm making a game in which I need to ask for the input from the user to get his choice and move the pieces accordingly. For context, Player 1(always go first) has piece 'A', 'B' and 'C', where Player 2 has 'D', 'E', 'F'. As for the direction, '0' as going up-left, '1' going upward, '2' going up-right, so on so for up to 7, where it indicates going leftward.

So for example, I choose 'A', then '4'. A_x and A_y should change from 0,0 to 1,1 but instead what I got was 7,2( I have added line of `cout << A_x << endl << A_y` to check the x and y value)

What went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code for piece 'A'

For `canMove1`, there is a while loop that will repeat when `canMove1 = false`, so that we can asking for the direction again when the current can't be moved to, and I have change `canMove1` to `true` the second the loop is entered.

```
switch (direction) {
                        case 1:
                            if (--A_x < 0 || --A_x == B_x && A_y == B_y || --A_x == C_x && A_y == C_y || --A_x == D_x &&
                            A_y == D_y || --A_x == E_x && A_y == E_y || --A_x == F_x && A_y == F_y){
                                cout << "Can't move to direction " << direction << endl;
                                canMove1 = false;
                            } else {
                                A_x -= 1; //update position
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (--A_x < 0 || ++A_y > 2 || --A_x == B_x && ++A_y == B_y || --A_x == C_x && ++A_y == C_y ||
                            --A_x == D_x && ++A_y == D_y || --A_x == E_x && ++A_y == E_y || --A_x == F_x && ++A_y == F_y){
                                cout << "Can't move to direction " << direction << endl;
                                canMove1 = false;
                            } else {
                                A_x -= 1; //update position
                                A_y += 1;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if (++A_y > 2 || A_x == B_x && ++A_y == B_y || A_x == C_x && ++A_y == C_y || A_x == D_x &&
                            ++A_y == D_y || A_x == E_x && ++A_y == E_y || A_x == F_x && ++A_y == F_y){
                                cout << "Can't move to direction " << direction << endl;
                                canMove1 = false;
                            } else {
                                A_y += 1; //update position
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            if (++A_x > 2 || ++A_y > 2 || ++A_x == B_x && ++A_y == B_y || ++A_x == C_x && ++A_y == C_y ||
                            ++A_x == D_x && ++A_y == D_y || ++A_x == E_x && ++A_y == E_y || ++A_x == F_x && ++A_y == F_y){
                                cout << "Can't move to direction " << direction << endl;
                                canMove1 = false;
                            } else {
                                A_x += 1; //update position
                                A_y += 1;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            if (++A_x > 2 || ++A_x == B_x && A_y == B_y || ++A_x == C_x && A_y == C_y || ++A_x == D_x &&
                            A_y == D_y || ++A_x == E_x && A_y == E_y || ++A_x == F_x && A_y == F_y){
                                cout << "Can't move to direction " << direction << endl;
                                canMove1 = false;
                            } else {
                                A_x += 1; //update position
                            }
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            if (++A_x > 2 || --A_y < 0 || ++A_x == B_x && --A_y == B_y || ++A_x == C_x && --A_y == C_y ||
                            ++A_x == D_x && --A_y == D_y || ++A_x == E_x && --A_y == E_y || ++A_x == F_x && --A_y == F_y){
                                cout << "Can't move to direction " << direction << endl;
                                canMove1 = false;
                            } else {
                                A_x += 1; //update position
                                A_y -= 1;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            if (--A_y < 0 || A_x == B_x && --A_y == B_y || A_x == C_x && --A_y == C_y || A_x == D_x &&
                            --A_y == D_y || A_x == E_x && --A_y == E_y || A_x == F_x && --A_y == F_y){
                                cout << "Can't move to direction " << direction << endl;
                                canMove1 = false;
                            } else {
                                A_y -= 1; //update position
                            }
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            if (--A_x < 0 || --A_y < 0 || --A_x == B_x && --A_y == B_y || --A_x == C_x && --A_y == C_y ||
                            --A_x == D_x && --A_y == D_y || --A_x == E_x && --A_y == E_y || --A_x == F_x && --A_y == F_y){
                                cout << "Can't move to direction " << direction << endl;
                                canMove1 = false;
                            } else {
                                A_x -= 1; //update position
                                A_y -= 1;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            cout << "Something went wrong with the direction..." << endl;
                            return 1;
                    }
```

Comment: All those `--A_x` and `++A_x`s are modifying `A_x`, is that intended? or did you actually want `A_x-1` and `A_x+1`?

Comment: @kmdreko For example, for case 1, I want to check if after moving upward, i.e. x - 1, will it be out of bound or equal to other pieces location, so I guess I want A_x - 1. Speaking of which, does that mean I should not use --A_x?